# c++ 11 typeid of string and sizeof nullptr

Tags: c++, string, c++11, nullptr, typeinfo

I'm a newbie in c++11 and I'm aware of `typeid().name()` and `nullptr`. I was just having some fun with a code but i found out that `sizeof(nullptr)` is `4` and moreover `typeid(str).name()` is something complex set of characters `NSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>
#include<typeinfo>

int main(){
    std::string str;
    std::cout<<sizeof(nullptr)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<typeid(str).name();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the output. Can someone kindly explain me ??

Comment: What did you expect them to be instead? You can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) that `std::string` is just a name for `std::basic_string<char>`, and _that_ has other type parameters which are just defaulted.

Comment: [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) could result in a [`std::nullptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) object. What this object is and what it contains, is implementation defined and not really relevant. As such the size of `nullptr` is also not relevant.

Comment: For future questions, please ask one question per question. Here you're asking about two different and unrelated things, which makes the question to broad and unfocused. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 3):

Both of these things are *implementation defined*.

> `sizeof(nullptr)` is `4`

I would assume that on that platform all pointers are size 4, and `nullptr`'s size was chosen to match that.

> `typeid(str).name()`

`std::string` is an alias for an instantiation of a template, `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. The name is further mangled to conform to your platform's format for executables. There may be a tool to "demangle" names provided by the platform.

Answer (score 1):

nullptr has type nullptr_t which is

`typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;`

so, it is implementation defined.

The complex string which you see looks like this because of name mangling C++ compiler is doing. Mangling is done in C++ because of overload, as same name can be used for different functions or methods; or a template is used for type declaration. More about it you can read in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++

It is also implementation defined and other compilers may use other schemes for name mangling.